# Validator to prevent empty TextBoxes with TextMode="Date"

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my textbox which I use in my form and I want to use a validator for preventing the user from leaving it empty. How can I do that?

```aspx
<asp:TextBox ID="basicinf_strtdate" runat="server" 
    TextMode="Date" Width="138px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78xxk8k.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) object that would target your TextBox and display an error message to prompt the user to correct their error if it was empty :

```
<!-- Your Textbox -->
<asp:TextBox ID="basicinf_strtdate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<!-- Validator to prevent empty submissions -->
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator"
                            runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="basicinf_strtdate"
                            Display="Static"
                            ErrorMessage="A Date is required!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <asp:TextBox ID="basicinf_strtdate" runat="server" 
>     TextMode="Date" Width="138px"></asp:TextBox>   
>  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
>                     ControlToValidate="basicinf_strtdate"
>                     Display="Static"
>                     ErrorMessage="*"
>                     runat="server"/>
> ```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RequiredFieldValidator`, if you are using a Button to submit or to save your date then make sure in that button you use `ValidationGroup="grp"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="basicinf_strtdate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Width="138px"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="basicinf_strtdate" ValidationGroup="grp" 
    ErrorMessage="Please select some date"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Hope this will help you.